# Laravel/Predis - Unknown response prefix

Tags: php, laravel, predis

Recently performed a small composer update on a Laravel project and started seeing errors such as this for some of our events. Exception is being thrown in predis (v1.1.10).

Any ideas why the responses aren't returning one of the expected values (from the source code it looks like the prefix should be +, $, *, : or -)

```
// Some examples of the exceptions we get
Unknown response prefix: '"'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: '"'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: '0'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: '3'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: 'e'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: 'e'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: 'e'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
Unknown response prefix: 'R'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379]
```

Stack trace

```
Predis\Protocol\ProtocolException Unknown response prefix: '0'. [tcp://someurl-europe-west2.redis.production.internal:6379] 
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:167 Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::onProtocolError
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:370 Predis\Connection\StreamConnection::read
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:120 Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::readResponse
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:112 Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::executeCommand
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:260 Predis\Connection\StreamConnection::connect
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:180 Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::getResource
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:288 Predis\Connection\StreamConnection::write
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:394 Predis\Connection\StreamConnection::writeRequest
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:110 Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::executeCommand
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:331 Predis\Client::executeCommand
    vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:314 Predis\Client::__call
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php:116 Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection::command
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php:220 Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection::__call
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/RedisQueue.php:140 Illuminate\Queue\RedisQueue::pushRaw
    vendor/laravel/horizon/src/RedisQueue.php:69 Laravel\Horizon\RedisQueue::pushRaw
    vendor/laravel/horizon/src/RedisQueue.php:52 Laravel\Horizon\RedisQueue::Laravel\Horizon\{closure}
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:317 Illuminate\Queue\Queue::enqueueUsing
    vendor/laravel/horizon/src/RedisQueue.php:53 Laravel\Horizon\RedisQueue::push
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php:57 Illuminate\Queue\Queue::pushOn
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php:133 Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager::queue
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:320 Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::broadcastEvent
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:243 Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::dispatch
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:450 event

// Our application, dispatches events like so
event(OneOfOurEvents);
```